# How to create deployment without images and later on, add new images?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to k8s and I'm trying to learn how to setup deployments.

I'm searching for a way to create a new deployment without any images. Over time, I will add new (0 or more) images (and specify thier desired state). As I don't know what images the deployment will contain in advance, I can't use any existing configuration files.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

- If it's possible, a command-line solution will be great.

Comment: What are you deploying if you don't have any images?

Comment: at start, nothing. but after some time, there will be images. the point is that I must initialize a deployement first.

Comment: That was my question: what is the point of having a deployment if you don't have anything to deploy yet. Create the deployment when you have something to deploy.

Comment: what if i create a deployement of a single pod, could i add new images later? (not changing exisitng images, but adding new images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start a single instance of nginx, you can do

```
 $  kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
```

But it is not possible to create any deployments without image.

```
$ kubectl run demo  --image=""
error: --image is required
```

If you want to edit your existing deployment, then you can run

```
$ kubectl edit deployments <deployment-name> -n <namespace>
```

You can also patch container with new image to existing deployments by running following command

```
$ kubectl patch deployment <deployment-name> -p   '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"myapp","image":"newimage"}]}}}}'
```

To replace image of a containers in deployment, run

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/<deployment-name> <container-name>=<image>
```

Comment: sory this doesn't help.what if i create a deployement of a single pod, could i add new images later? (not changing exisitng images, but adding new images)

Comment: you can edit you deployment by running `kubectl edit deployment <deployment-name> -n <namespace> ` then edit the spec. You can add containers with new image. You can also replace existing image by running `kubectl set image deployment/<deployment-name> <container-name?=image:v2 `

Comment: `kubectl edit deployment <deployment-name> -n <namespace>` - is there a way to specify the new images from the comand line? I can't edit in run time a k8s confuguration file.

Comment: I have updated answer. does that satisfy your question?

Comment: you can also check kubectl cheat sheet https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/